# Resolving ambiguous instance for multiparam type class

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm developing a specialized numerical data processing library, and I've come across an error that I can't figure out how to fix.  I think it'll be easier to show an example first and then explain my problem.  I also apologize for the strange names, I'm having to obfuscate for legal purposes.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances     #-}

data MyError = MyError String deriving (Eq, Show)

data MyList    = MyList [Double] deriving (Eq, Show)
data NamedList = NamedList String MyList deriving (Eq, Show)

class MyNum a b ret where
    myAdd       :: a -> b -> Either MyError ret
    myLessThan  :: a -> b -> Either MyError Bool

instance MyNum MyList Double MyList where
    myAdd (MyList xs) x = Right $ MyList $ map (+x) xs
    myLessThan (MyList xs) x = Right $ all (< x) xs

instance MyNum NamedList Double NamedList where
    myAdd (NamedList n l) x = fmap (NamedList n) $ myAdd l x
    myLessThan (NamedList n l) x = myLessThan l x
```

If I try to compile this, I get the error

```
No instance for (MyNum MyList Double ret0)
  arising from a use of `myLessThan'
The type variable `ret0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Note: there is a potential instance available:
  instance MyNum MyList Double MyList
    -- Defined at testing_instances.hs:13:10
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for (MyNum MyList Double ret0)
In the expression: myLessThan l x
In an equation for `myLessThan':
    myLessThan (NamedList n l) x = myLessThan l x
In the instance declaration for `MyNum NamedList Double NamedList'
```

Because the compiler can't figure out which specific instance of `MyNum` to use for `MyList`.  It works for `myAdd` because the return type for `MyNum` is easily derived, but it can't figure it out for `myLessThan`.  I want to use this typeclass so that I can easily add fine-grained error handling throughout, and because my actual code has the equivalent of +, -, *, /, <, <=, >, and >=, and I want to make an instance for `MyNum Double MyList MyList`, `MyNum MyList MyList MyList`, and similar ones for `NamedList`.  Unless there's an easier way to do this, it's so that I can have polymorphic commutative operators.

However, I can't figure out what type signature to add to `myLessThan` for the second instance so that it can know which instance to use.  I know one solution would be to split the arithmetic and comparison operators into two separate type classes, but I would like to avoid doing so if at all possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [functional dependencies](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functional_dependencies) to specify that "`ret` is uniquely determined by `a` and `b`".

```
...
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
...
class MyNum a b ret | a b -> ret where
...
```

This lets the typechecker know that it can pick the correct instance definition, knowing only the `a` and `b` from the arguments in your:

```
myLessThan (NamedList n l) x = myLessThan l x
```

The compiler will now complain if you define an additional instance with the same `a` and `b` but a different `ret`, such as

```
instance MyNum MyList Double SomeOtherType where
```

Comment: This is a previously unfamiliar construct in Haskell for me, and exactly what I was needing, thanks!

Comment: @bheklilr glad I could help. You might also want to learn about TypeFamilies, which are easier to work with in some ways and more powerful.

Answer (score 4):

As jberryman noted, you can use `TypeFamilies`. And this is how:

```
-{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances     #-}
+{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

-class MyNum a b ret where
-    myAdd       :: a -> b -> Either MyError ret
+class MyNum a b where
+    type Ret a b
+    myAdd       :: a -> b -> Either MyError (Ret a b)

-instance MyNum MyList Double MyList where
+instance MyNum MyList Double where
+    type Ret MyList Double = MyList

-instance MyNum NamedList Double NamedList where
+instance MyNum NamedList Double where
+    type Ret NamedList Double = NamedList
```

I just moved `ret` type from class parameter to [associated type](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Type_families#An_associated_type_synonym_example) `Ret`.
It is a `TypeFamily`-way to state that there is function from class parameters `a` and `b` to `Ret`.

Comment: I like that it removes the third explicit type parameter from the `MyNum` class.  Does anyone have any information on which one performs better, though?  I don't mind a bit more cluttered code if it means that it runs faster, or if type families are more efficient, I'd rather use that solution.

Comment: As far as I am aware, both solutions will have equal performance. You can check the compiled core to see if there is any difference - but in this case I wouldn't expect there to be one.

Comment: @ocharles  I'll try profiling it when I get the chance, and I'll try to post an update later with my results